# Markov kernels and Chapman-Kolmogorov equations

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability

Let $(\Omega_1,\mathcal{A}_1)$ and $(\Omega_2,\mathcal{A}_2)$ be measurable spaces. A map
\begin{align}
    K: \Omega_1 \times \mathcal{F}_2 \to [0,+\infty]
\end{align}
is called a transition kernel from $\Omega_1$ to $\Omega_2$ if

- $K(.,A_2)$ is $\mathcal{A}_1$-measurable for any $A_2\in\mathcal{A}_2$.
- $K(\omega_1,.)$ is a measure on $(\Omega_2,\mathcal{A}_2)$ for any $\omega_1\in\mathcal{A}_1$.

We usually name the kernel according to the type of measures it creates. For instance, if the measures generated by $K$ are probability measures, $K$ is called a Markov kernel.

Also, we know that for Polish spaces and, in particular, real-valued processes, the kernels define regular conditional probabilities.

MCMC by Casella and Robert has the following equation
$$
P((X_1, X_2)\in A_1\times A_2) = \int_{A_1}K(y,A_2)K(x,dy)
$$

Clearly, we may write
$$
P(x,A) = \int_A K(x,dy)
$$
as the kernel defines a measure for fixed $x$. However, I'm having a hard time doing the computations for the cases with more than one variable that leads to the Chapman-Kolmogorov equations. I'd like a little help with them.